# Count url types with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to count the URL types of a list. I have a list which contains image URLs and YouTube video URLs. I want to count how much URLs are YouTube links, and how much URLs are images.

Example:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="./images/demo-4.gif" alt="image" data-type="pic"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="pic" /></a></li>
<li><a href="./images/demo-4.gif" alt="image" data-type="pic"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="pic" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4jLRi5Lf_o" data-type="video"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="video" /></a></li>
<li><a href="./images/demo-4.gif" alt="image" data-type="pic"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="pic" /></a></li>
<li><a href="./images/demo-4.gif" alt="image" data-type="pic"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="pic" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4jLRi5Lf_o" data-type="video"><img src="./images/tumb_2.png" alt="video" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use like this:

```
var imgLen = $('a[data-type="pic"]').length;
var vidLen = $('a[data-type="video"]').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var imgLength = $('li a[data-type="pic"]').size();
var vidLength = $('li a[data-type="video"]').size();
```

**or**

```
 var imgLength = $('li a[data-type="pic"]').length;
 var vidLength = $('li a[data-type="video"]').length;
```

The **.size()** method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the **.length** property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("There are " + $('a').length + " links");
console.log("of which " + $('[data-type="pic"]').length + " are images");
console.log("and " + $('[data-type="video"]').length + " are videos");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```